# Customer login weird issue

Tags: customer, login, dashboard

I got big issue on website. I have took over website for some changes from other company so I don't know where to look for the issue. The issue is:
Customer can create new account without any problem but when customer is logged in there is no dashboard at all. All you can see is header with navigation and below that where dashboard suppose to be is blank.

Anyone got any idea or any solution to fix it please ??

Regards,
William

Link to scree shoot here:

http://caveo-security.com/customer_login.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the webserver (e.g. Apache, nginx) logs for the cause of the 500 error, and will most likely also find the cause of the "half page"-dashboard-error there.

The webserver logs are different from Magento's own logs in `var/log` and you should ask your hosting provider where to find them.

Also, please specify your Magento version. In 1.x, you can enable the Developer Mode either in the webserver configuration or in the `index.php` file. In Magento 2.x, you can enable this mode with calling this in the Magento root directory:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

You shouldn't enable this in the live-system, though, as this will lead to more errors and error messages being shown. Also, in Magento 1.x, theres the file `errors/local.xml` (or `errors/local.xml.sample`, if it is a fresh install) where you can define to have a mail sent with the full error message and stacktrace if anything goes wrong.

All paths are from the Magento root directory.

Comment: Sorry I forgot magento version is 1.9.3.3.

Comment: No problem. The server logs I mentioned will most likely show a  `PHP - Fatal Error` message that blocks the bottom of the page from being rendered.

Comment: "A 500 error can be for a range of issues, normally related to poor practice in code standards or the wrong PHP version.

The error log will be a file called error_log in the directory the file is held in :-)

So in this instance, it'll be inside customer/account/"  That's the answer from web host provider :/

Comment: Ok, do. you have an error_log in your Magento root directorY?

Comment: found it solved now thank you very much Simon

Answer (score 0):

What are you getting in your header responses when you login? Is there any http 500 errors in browser network tab in developer option? And you can also check if by mistake there is an die, exit or appropriate code left in AccountController.php

Comment: I'm not getting any errors at all. Even error log is empty. Where can I find AccountController.php please ?

Comment: I've check it and it's all good there...

Comment: in network tab i got placeholder.html in red and "fail to load response data".

Comment: found one error: GET https://www.tacura.co.uk/customer/account/ 500 (). Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Look for coding errors indexAction() in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php. In case if you have override it then you have to look in that namespace .

Answer (score 0):

That was the problem !

Thank you Simon very mych

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getName() on null in /home/tacuraco/public_html/app/design/frontend/design/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml on line 57